# Improper SpriteBatch Rotation

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-4.0, spritebatch

I'm trying to get a rotated `Texture2D` to properly fit within/fill the bounds of a rotated `Polygon` (my own class), but it refuses to work properly. The `SpriteBatch` method I am using is:

`spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height), null, color, Rotation, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);`

However, the only important bits in this are the `Rectangle` and the origin, which is currently set to `Vector2.Zero`. When the above is run, it produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZKat.png) image, where the `Texture2D` (a filled red square) is offset from the `Polygon` (the lime wireframe) by a value of `(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2)`. However, the rotation is correct, since both shapes have parallel sides.

I have tried:

`spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height), null, color, Rotation, new Vector2(Width / 2, Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);`

The only difference in this call is that I changed the origin (the point around which the `Texture2D` *should* be rotated) to `new Vector2(Width / 2, Height / 2)`, which results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aicXi.png) image, where the `Texture2D` is offset from the `Polygon` by a value of `(-Width, -Height)`, but it still rotates with the `Polygon`.

Another error that occurs is that when using a different `Texture2D` with a different width and height from the first-- although it should produce the same result since the `destinationRectangle` field does not change-- it is different in the program, as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E0sB.png) image. Again, this uses the *exact same call* as the previous, just with a different image (with different dimensions).

Any help on either of these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both of my problems lies in one mistake:

*SpriteBatch applies the rotation around the origin **before** applying scale translation.*

To explain this, here's an example:

You have a `Texture2D` of size `(16, 16)`, and want it to fill a `(48, 48)` size `destinationRectangle` while rotating around origin point `(destinationRectangle.Width / 2, destinationRectangle.Height / 2)` (which is equal to `(24, 24)`). So, you want to end up with a square rotated around its center point.

First, `SpriteBatch` will rotate the `Texture2D` around point `(24, 24)`, which, because the `Texture2D` has not yet been scaled and therefore is of size `(16, 16)`, will result in an improper and unexpected result. After this, it will be scaled, making it just a larger version of the poorly rotated square.

To remedy this problem, **use** `(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2)` **instead of** `(destinationRectangle.Width / 2, destinationRectangle.Height / 2)` **as the origin point.**

Example:`spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height), null, color, Rotation, new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);`

Further explanation can be found [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49350/xna-spritebatch-draw-with-rotation-scaling-and-origin) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51508/weird-behavior-with-xna-spritebatch-draw-origin?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=M_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Graphics_SpriteBatch_Draw

For proper rotation you need to make sure `origin` is correct,

Either it'd be `0.5f, 0.5f` if it's a normalized value, else it'd be `width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f`.

Or any other appropriate corner to rotate around in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The origin adjusts the center of the rotation based on the source rectangle. (When passed as `null` as in your case, the source rectangle is the entire Texture.

Remember that order is important when it comes to Translation, Rotation, and Scale.

The rotation is applied at the translated origin of the source rectangle, allowing the rotation of individual frames of a sprite sheet.

The following code should produce the expected output:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.Center.X, (int)Position.Center.Y, Width, Height), null, color, Rotation, new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
```